# awaiting an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I don't really know when/how to use async & await. For example I have this function that returns a promise:

```
async function fn1(){
  return await fetch('localhost:3000')
}
```

Now I have two options:

1. use `.then`

   ```
   fn1.then((result) => {
     console.log(result)
   })
   ```
2. use `await`

   ```
   const data = await fn1()
   console.log(data)
   ```

I'd prefer the second approach but this would make me wrap it inside an `async` function which I have to `await` or use `.then` to use it.

I've seen some tutorials that use `async`/`await` and `.then` at the same time but from what I can tell it's not good practice.

Comment: "*I'd appreciate it if someone would clarify it for me*" not sure what clarification you need. Everything you said before this sentence is correct.

Comment: `.then` is for the promise. `await` is for the async await. Its different use cases. These works exactly the same but different syntax

Comment: Agree with VLAZ, I'm not sure what's the question. It sounds more like an assertion and waiting for supporters/challengers... Also, minor correction: we don't have to `return await...` we can simply `return` since what's returned is a promise regardless if we add the `await` or not AFAIK.

Comment: @VLAZ What I don't understand is what should I do when I want to get the data of an async function, should I use ```.then``` or ```await```?

Comment: You should probably choose one style and stick with it, try not to mix the two. AFAIK it's more recommended to use the newer style: async/await mainly because it's clearer but also because of V8 optimizations.

Comment: Writing asynchronous JavaScript is simpler with the async/await syntax. It makes the code look like it's synchronous, but it's asynchronous and non-blocking behind the scenes. Hence reducing the boilerplate around promises, and the "don't break the chain" limitation of chaining promises.
[A good example in docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#rewriting_promise_code_with_asyncawait)

Comment: @Khaled yes, you should use `.then` or `await`. Both are correct. `await` might be easier to work in many cases, so if you have no preference, go for that one. But there is no One True Way.

Comment: @Khaled An async function returns a promise. A promise can be used with either `await` or `.then()`, use whatever is appropriate for the caller. It has nothing to do with the promise being created through an async function or not.